# nunit problem loading exe

Tags: dll, nunit, load, exe

following situation:

- tests.dll contains a bunch of unit
  tests
- program.exe contains some to be tested
  classes
- tests.dll contains tests using the
  classes in program.exe
- therefore tests.dll has a reference
  on program.exe
- nunit-agent.exe loads tests.dll and this then loads program.exe

--> basically in the nunit environment program.exe is used like a dll.
'misusing' an exe as dll is possible as i just wrote a little test application that also references program.exe and uses some classes defined in there and this runs fine ...

BUT in nunit i get a BadImageFormatException as soon as tests are loaded that use code defined in program.exe

is this a bug in nunit's reflection mechanism or is there a reason for that?

thx 
tobi

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if the .exe is compiled for x86 and you are running the tests on a 64 bit OS.  If this is the case you may choose to use nunit-x86.exe for running the tests.

Comment: in my situation everything is done on the same 64 bit windows 7 machine ... so this does not seem to be the problem here

Comment: By default Visual Studio 2010 targets the x86 platform when you create a new .exe project. Your .exe may be compiled for x86 which may cause your problems. Check the project settings in VS for the .exe.

Comment: This fixed my similar issue.  I changed the EXE that was causing nunit problems from x86 to AnyCpu in the project properties and then it worked.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this! I had a 'any cpu' unit test library in .net 4.0 testing a 'x86' .net 2.0 exe. (So i could use better mocking tools etc.